# Paypal Express Checkout payment: Magento 2

Tags: magento2, payment, paypal

When choosing a payment method paypal does not always come Billing Address, and because of this, payment does not go through and everything goes according to plan.
Has anyone encountered this problem? Why in some cases does not come Billing Address?

Answer (score 0):

the checkout configuration has additional `Display Billing Address On` option (`Stores` -> `Configuration` -> `Checkout` -> `Checkout Options`). It has two possible values:

- Payment Method - billing address is displayed per payment method
- Payment Page - billing address is displayed above payment methods

The second option should solve your problem without any changes in the code base. Also, it might be useful for some methods like PayPal Express Checkout and allows to set billing address different to shipping.

Comment: So there is added a new form. and it does not suit me